# Oracle sql - SP2-0552: Bind variable "T_END" not declared error, but "T_START" is fine, why? Both use TO_DATE()

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Check this Oracle sql script:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 200000;

declare
  start timestamp; 
  fin timestamp;
  opr varchar2(64);
  op varchar2(64);
  ext_act varchar2(64);
  time_sum float;
  counter integer := 1;
  query1 varchar2(4096):='select * from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end and rownum < 500000 order by IH.EVENT_DATE';
  query2 varchar2(4096):='select * from (select * from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end) where rownum < 500000';
  query3 varchar2(4096):='select * from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end fetch first 500000 rows only';


begin
    FOR query IN (SELECT column_value FROM table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(query1, query2, query3))) loop 
        dbms_output.put_line('This is query ' || counter);
            for i in 1..10 loop
                start:=systimestamp;
                exec :opr       := '88000001';
                exec :op        := 'CHANGE_OWNER';
                exec :ext_act   := 'NOT_APPLICABLE';
                exec :t_start   :=TO_DATE('2018/07/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
                exec :t_end     :=TO_DATE('2020/05/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
                query;
                fin := systimestamp;
                duration := fin - start;
                dbms_output.put_line('Time taken for query' || counter || ' for run ' || i || ': ' || duration);
                time_sum := time_sum || duration;
            end loop;
            dbms_output.put_line('Avg time for query' || counter || ': ' || time_sum / 10);
            time_sum := 0;
        counter:=counter+1;
    end loop;
end
```

I have error: `SP2-0552: Bind variable "T_END" not declared.`, but `T_START` is fine and is before `T_END`. If `T_END` is bad, why `T_START` is not? What is wrong?

Originally they were `t1` and `t2`, but the error is the same: no error for `t1` and error for `t2`.

Comment: `t_start` isn't fine either - comment out line 23 and it'll complain about `t_start` instead of `t_end`. Oracle often parses code backwards... Unclear what you're trying to do though. You have lots of other issues too, like `start` being a reserved word. using `exec` within PL/SQL (it's a client command, not PL/SQL or SQL), and `query;` as a statement - perhaps you meant to `execute immediate query using ...` and supplying the bind values? You also have to select *into* something, even with dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If `T_END` is bad, why `T_START` is not?

They are both bad - neither is declared.

SQL Developer (I guess - or SQL*Plus, or SQLcl) is reporting the first high-level issue it finds, which is with an undeclared bind variable. At that level it isn't looking at the PL/SQL itself or passing anything to the database engine to be verified, it's doing its own scan to see if it thinks the code is sane - and deciding it isn't, so it stops immediately, without doing any real work.

It's parsing the block backwards so it sees and reports `t_end` first, and stops there. If you comment out that line (23) then it will report that `t_start` is not declared instead.

None of the bind variables you refer to are defined in the client - you would need `variable` and `exec` commands *before* the PL/SQL block; `exec` is itself a client shorthand for an anonymous PL/SQL block, so it doesn't belong where you have it - it's a client command, not PL/SQL or SQL.

Some of the other issues in your code:

- you are using reserved words (like `start`) which are illegal;
- you've declared `opr`, `op` and `ext_act` as local PL/SQL variables - *not* bind variables - but don't use those;
- you've declare `time_sum` as a float, but you're working with the differences between timestamps, which are intervals;
- you are referring to `query` as if it's a value, but it's effectively a record - to use the value returned by the cursor query you would need to refer to `query.column_value`, or alias that in the query for a more helpful name;
- you are trying to run `query;` as if it's a complete statement not a variable (or record, see previous point) - you need to treat it as dynamic SQL, which leads to:
- you either need to use `query.column_value` as a dynamic cursor and loop over the results, or change the query to return a single scalar value, which you still have to select *into* something;
- `time_sum || duration` is doing string concatenation - you presumably meant to use addition;
- probably some other things I've forgotten.

I think this does what you were aiming at:

```
declare
  l_start timestamp; 
  l_fin timestamp;
  l_result pls_integer;
  l_duration interval day to second;
  l_time_sum interval day to second := interval '0' second;
  l_counter integer := 1;
  l_query1 varchar2(4096):='select count(*) from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end and rownum < 500000 order by IH.EVENT_DATE';
  l_query2 varchar2(4096):='select count(*) from (select * from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end) where rownum < 500000';
  l_query3 varchar2(4096):='select count(*) from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end fetch first 500000 rows only';

begin
    FOR query IN (SELECT column_value as str FROM table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(l_query1, l_query2, l_query3))) loop 
        dbms_output.put_line('This is query ' || l_counter);
        for i in 1..10 loop
            l_start:=systimestamp;
            execute immediate query.str
                into l_result            -- not used
                using '88000001',        -- opr
                      'CHANGE_OWNER',    -- op
                      'NOT_APPLICABLE',  -- ext_act
                      DATE '2018-07-01', -- t_start
                      DATE '2020-05-01'; -- t_end
            l_fin := systimestamp;
            l_duration := l_fin - l_start;
            dbms_output.put_line('Time taken for query' || l_counter || ' for run ' || i || ': ' || l_duration);
            l_time_sum := l_time_sum + l_duration;
        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line('Avg time for query' || l_counter || ': ' || (l_time_sum / 10));
        l_time_sum := interval '0' second;
        l_counter:=l_counter+1;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

You could also put the query strings into a collection and then just loop over that, without having to use a cursor and query:

```
declare
  l_start timestamp; 
  l_fin timestamp;
  l_result pls_integer;
  l_duration interval day to second;
  l_time_sum interval day to second := interval '0' second;
  l_queries sys.odcivarchar2list := new sys.odcivarchar2list(
      'select count(*) from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end and rownum < 500000 order by IH.EVENT_DATE',
      'select count(*) from (select * from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end) where rownum < 500000',
      'select count(*) from ITEM_HISTORY IH join PACKAGE P on P.PACKAGE_NAME = IH.PACKAGE_NAME where OPERATOR_ID = :opr and (IH.OPERATION != :op OR IH.EVENT_DATE = IH.INSTALLATION_DATE) and IH.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_ACTION != :ext_act and IH.EVENT_DATE >= :t_start and IH.EVENT_DATE < :t_end fetch first 500000 rows only');

begin
    for l_counter in 1..l_queries.count loop
        dbms_output.put_line('This is query ' || l_counter);
        for i in 1..10 loop
            l_start:=systimestamp;
            execute immediate l_queries(l_counter)
                into l_result            -- not used
                using '88000001',        -- opr
                      'CHANGE_OWNER',    -- op
                      'NOT_APPLICABLE',  -- ext_act
                      DATE '2018-07-01', -- t_start
                      DATE '2020-05-01'; -- t_end
            l_fin := systimestamp;
            l_duration := l_fin - l_start;
            dbms_output.put_line('Time taken for query' || l_counter || ' for run ' || i || ': ' || l_duration);
            l_time_sum := l_time_sum + l_duration;
        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line('Avg time for query' || l_counter || ': ' || (l_time_sum / 10));
        l_time_sum := interval '0' second;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a7e3951d6cba637f5215603466d6fff6) using dummy dynamic queries as we don't have your tables (but hopefully you don't have a table called `package` either?)

If you don't want to pass the literals directly in the `using` clause then you could declare and populate local PL/SQL variables and refer to those instead; or you could declare client-level bind variables (`var`/`exec`), but there doesn't seem to be any advantage in doing that.

I've guessed/assumed a count would give you the timing information you want, allowing a single scalar results, which you ignore anyway. That's simpler than looping over the actual results - and it seems unlikely you're trying to compare the overall fetch times for 50000 rows. Also the `order by` in the first dynamic query probably isn't doing what you think, and means the three aren't quite equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You mean, if I want to benchmark the 3 queries, counting would be enough? Is it real enough? I do want to compare fetch time actually. 
Another thing is, about query 1, I know it is incorrect, but it is what we have now; 2 and 3 are my new versions. We want to make sure that at the same time of correcting 1, there is performance improvement after my commit, as my initial tests shows 2 is even slower, but 3 is faster.

Comment: BTW I tried the two versions, but got the same error: `Error report -
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -
ORA-06512: at line 17
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
` the line is `execute immediate ...`

Comment: If you're expecting exactly the same results then arguably the fetch time would be the same - and will probably swamp any difference in query execution time. Though if you look at the execution plans they'll probably be very similar anyway, I think. I guess 2 might be slower if it can't push the rownum predicate into the subquery. If you do want to fetch, though, then you need a dynamic cursor loop.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the fiddle shows both queries working?

Comment: Yeah, my error, I changed `select count(*)` to `select *`. With count they work; executing...

Comment: With `select *` you would need to fetch into either multiple variables or a record type representing all columns; and deal with multiple rows - with a dynamic cursor, or possibly a collection. But really it depends exactly what you're trying to test.

Comment: Got my result, avg time for query 1 is 44s, 2: 51s, 3: 12s(only counting). Will tell my team to go for 3. Thanks!